# DecimalFormat and Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, gson, decimalformat

So I have a dynamic data which is a **double** and I'm trying to add that to a **HashMap** and using **Gson** I'm converting it into a **Json**. sometimes the data can be 0.00 or 0.0, then I want to add only 0 to HashMap. For this purpose, I'm using **DecimalFormat** to format the data as I want(as I mentioned above) but when I do that It's taking the value as a String in JSON. When I try to print it then it's printing it as a number but when I add it to hashmap and convert it into JSON It's a string. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, can anyone help me on this. here's the code.

```
 HashMap<String, Object> field = new LinkedHashMap<>();
 double heading = 0.00;
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
 field.put("data", decimalFormat.format(heading));
 Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls().disableHtmlEscaping().create();  // create a GsonBuilder to convert the hashmap to a Json String.
        String jsonOutput = gson.toJson(field);
 System.out.println( jsonOutput );
```

consider the **field** Hashmap to be a big dataset then the output is

```
 field{
data: "0"
}
```

but I want it to be

```
field{
data: 0
}
```

I don't want the 0 to in **" "**. Is there any other alternative to DecimalFormat or is there a way to make the hashmap to take it as a number.

Answer (score 2):

You can put in a Double directly. Gson knows how to output that.

```
field.put("data", heading)
```

> sometimes the data can be 0.00 or 0.0, then I want to add only 0 to HashMap.

I propose that `0.00`, `0.0` and `0` are all the same number and that you should not care which one ends up in the resulting JSON. Any JSON parser will be able to read it back correctly.

What would throw the JSON parser (and the consumer) off is if you wrote it as a String.

Comment: Yes, 0.00, 0.0 and 0 are all the same. what if there is a case where the data can be an integer I mean as I said the data can change so is there a way to check it that the data is whether an integer or double and add the value according to the hashmap?

Comment: JSON does not make a difference between integers and floating point. All numbers are stored as `double`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the digits after decimal. then you can try below code:

```
field.put("data", (long) heading);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here the `Decimalformat` formats the output to string. Check the output type of the `format()`.

you can parse the output to integer like

```
     field.put("data", Double.parseDouble( decimalFormat.format(heading)));
```

Comment: I can't parse it into an Integer as I said the data is Double and sometimes I get 0.00 or 0.0 so if I do it then it'll fail when the data is a double value.

Comment: @Srikar Edited. Instead of Integer you can use Double to parse.

Comment: But `heading` is already a `double`. Why this round-trip with the decimal formatter?